# Multiple Identity for a single user in XMPP

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, user-profile

I would like to know, under the XMPP architecture, would it be possible for a single user to have multiple identity. For example, a user can have a profile as a teacher and at the same time have a different profile as a consultant; such that in the student's contact list, the user is displayed as teacher; and in the customer's contact, the user is displayed as consultant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not think there is such feature defined in XMPP standard of extensions. You would have to build something custom.

Comment: Hi Mickael, thanks for you quick reply. Instead of customizing the architecture, do you have any insight on how to achieve something similar through extension of XMPP.